# Protractor sendkeys not working: an x display is required for keycode conversions

Tags: node.js, angularjs, testing, selenium, protractor

I am trying to run Protractor e2e tests inside a Vagrant VM using headless Chrome.
I managed to get it working by using Xvfb but when I run a test to fill a form I get an error: **unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb**

All tests run fine but as soon as I use getKeys() (e.g. element(by.model('user.email')).sendKeys('admin'); ) I get this error, even though I am already using Xvfb.

I'm running:

- AngularJS sample app generated with the Yeoman angular-fullstack generator
- Nodejs version 0.10.30, installed with nvm
- Vagrant 1.6.3
- VirtualBox 4.3.14
- Host OS Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits
- Guest OS Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits
- chrome 37.0.2062.94
- chromedriver 2.10.267517

I use the following shell script to start Selenium and Xvfb:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> webdriver-manager start &
>
> Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x8 &
>
> export DISPLAY=:1

I also added "export DISPLAY=:1" to /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome. 
Again, tests without sendKeys() run fine.

**What I have done so far:**

- I'm running 32 bits Ubuntu so I downloaded chromedriver 2.10 32 bits but that didn't help
- I ran chromedriver with --verbose and checked the logs but that only shows the same error
- I fiddled with the Xvfb screen dimension settings, didn't help either
- I checked some source code here: https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/blob/master/keycode_text_conversion_x.cc and found the error message on line 196.
  It's triggered when the command gfx::GetXDisplay() (line 193) doesn't get a display object. I suspect that it might be just the DISPLAY variable I export in /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome but I'm not sure and have no idea how to fix it.

I would like to know how I can get sendfkeys() working with headless Chrome inside a Vagrant VM.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure [seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/example/conf.js#L4) matches your selenium server and avoid setting `chromeOnly` since that will effectively avoid using the headless selenium server.

Also, Xvfb needs to run before `webdriver-manager` and you're missing `xvfb-run` given you seem to need it to do the [X authority dance](https://github.com/elgalu/headless/blob/9ca476c42f/headless_install.sh#L37) for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:1

Xvfb $DISPLAY -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x8 &
sleep 1

xvfb-run webdriver-manager start &
```

In case you're interested I've setup a headless docker based solution with optional VNC access plus video recording: https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply, Leo.
I tested this but it's still not working. I also ran it on my Mac at work which is 64 bits but the same error occurs.

Comment: You mean you run a VM Guest OS Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits? And using `xvfb-run` gives the same error as before for sendKeys?

Comment: At home I run 32 bits Ubuntu 14.04 as both host and guest OS, at work OSX host and 64 bits Ubuntu 14.04 guest. Both give the exact same error. Could it be some dependency I need to install? I checked several blogs and SO which give me the same info to get everything running. If you need more info please let me know and thanks again for your effort!

Comment: I have no other clues except to give it a try to https://github.com/elgalu/headless but that's going to take you more time..

Comment: I will surely have a look at it. If you are absolutely sure the code you posted is correct then I guess the problem is elsewhere. I'll do some more research and fiddling and post my progress here, thanks.

Comment: I managed to get some progress! In protractor.conf.js I had to set "chromeOnly" to false so it uses the Selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub instead of chromedriver only. I haven't yet figured out why it doesn't work with chromedriver only. I will do some more research and then accept your answer and edit it to add this. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome Danny!! Yes, `chromeOnly` effectively will avoid using the headless selenium server: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/example/chromeOnlyConf.js#L3 sorry I didn't see that coming.

Comment: Make sure `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'` matcher your headless server. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/example/conf.js#L4

Comment: Hey Danny, your edits were rejected idk why. So I edited myself. Thanks for accepting!!