# keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

Google Chrome last version from official repository

ChromeDriver last version installed

Selenium last version installed

My **wdio.conf.js**

```
desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: process.env.BROWSER || 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
          ],
      prefs: {
        'download.default_directory': __dirname + '/tmp/test/download',
        'download.prompt_for_download': false
      }
    }
  },
```

**My error**

Some test working and after get error.

```
  ✓ restore password (500ms)

[07:07:40]  COMMAND POST     "/wd/hub/session/21b26bbb-c9ee-4a4e-89de-ac6e8180fe9c/element/34/value"
[07:07:40]  DATA         {"value":["s","i","m","u","l","a","t","i","o","n"]}
[07:07:41]  INFO    Retry #1
[07:07:41]  ERROR   ServerError unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb
[07:07:41]  INFO    Retry #2
[07:07:41]  ERROR   ServerError unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb
[07:07:41]  INFO    Gave up after 3 tries
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Consider providing a context for your problem. Make your question as clear as possible so people understand enough to help you

Answer (score 1):

Sending keys currently does not work without a (virtual) XServer.

There is an open ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1772

And also a workaround, replace the `sendkeys` call with JavaScript: https://github.com/Automattic/wp-e2e-tests/issues/515#issuecomment-301165065

Or you have to use Xvfb, like the driver error message and the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running on some sort of **Linux**/**UNIX** distro/env, which you should have pointed out in the first place. 
The traceback error suggests you don't have an **Xvfb** (X11 server) instance necessary to graphically render what I presume is a **setValue** command.

Please see the answer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731647/protractor-sendkeys-not-working-an-x-display-is-required-for-keycode-conversion)** question, which will probably give you the tools to bypass this issue. (also, possible duplicate)

Btw, I've copied your **wdio.config.js** setup and successfully ran a few tests, so that is not your problem.

```
 [13:33:41]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/66c3c740-3089-47f4-a366-a2adf2cae09d/elements"
 [13:33:41]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":"div[connectqa-device=\"pending\"]"}
 [13:33:41]  RESULT              [{"ELEMENT":"12"}]
.[13:33:41]  COMMAND    DELETE   "/wd/hub/session/66c3c740-3089-47f4-a366-a2adf2cae09d"
 [13:33:41]  DATA                {}
 [13:33:42]  RESULT              null

4 passing (18.50s)
```

Comment: docker exec idg sh -c "export DISPLAY=:99"
          docker exec idg sh -c "nohup Xvfb $DISPLAY +extension RANDR > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
          docker exec idg sh -c "sleep 3"
Maybe this command not right?